# AutoHotkey with Outlook (move email)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to set up a shortcut so that I can easily move emails to my "Actioned" folder from my inbox.  I've set this up as a Quick Action in Outlook, but the key combination is limited to a very awkward Ctrl + Shift + 1

So I'm tring to map this key combination to something nicer, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> using AutoHotKey.

I can't seem to get it to work at all.
This is what I have currently:

```
^!::Send {Ctrl down} {LShift down} {1} {Ctrl up} {LShift up}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have Autohotkey, but based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/157625/27017) I can suggest an (imperfect) workaround. ***If*** you only have one Quick Action that you need a shortcut for, and ***if*** you don't mind making it the first in the list, you should be able to use this command:

```
!1::Send, {ALTDOWN}H{ALTUP}QS return
```

Answer (score 0):

**^** for Ctrl and **!** for Alt are modifiers and are used to combine Ctrl and 
Alt with other keys.

If you want to use them directly, try

```
Control & Alt::Send {Ctrl down}{LShift down}1{Ctrl up}{LShift up}
```

or

```
Control & Alt::Send ^+1
```

Using Control or Alt as Hotkeys will interfere with the normal use of these keys so it's better to select a hotkey that includes a normal key.

It is also possible to limit this key to windows with Outlook in the title by using this code:

```
SetTitleMatchmode, 2
#IfWinActive, Outlook
Control & Alt::Send {Ctrl down}{LShift down}1{Ctrl up}{LShift up}
#IfWinActive
```